# How to edit DataTable() Print Title

Tags: jquery, datatable

I tried searching in google how to change datatable title and i found this thread [Datatables API: how to change Print page title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386742/datatables-api-how-to-change-print-page-title)

The best answer for this thread is

```
 var table = $('table').DataTable({
   buttons: [
      extend: 'print',
      title: function(){
         return foo.title
      }
   ]
});
```

I don't understand how it works using this gives me error in console 'indexOf..'

this is the picture of what i want to change
[DataTable Website Customized Print Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1LpD.png)

**EDIT 1** trying this code

```
 var table = $('table').DataTable({
   buttons: [
      extend: 'print',
      title: function(){
        var printTitle = 'New Title';
         return printTitle.title
      }
   ]
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Take a look at:**

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/customisation.html

You can use  title in buttons extension:

```
title: 'Datatables example: Customisation of the print view window'
```

Or just tag

```
<caption>Datatables example: Customisation of the print view window</caption>
```

Fiddle with a example:
https://jsfiddle.net/f14ykjem/1/

```
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    $('#example').DataTable( {
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: 'ButtonLabelHere',
                    title: 'Datatables example: Customisation of the print view window',
                    customize: function ( win ) {
                        $(win.document.body)
                            .css( 'font-size', '10pt' )
                            .prepend(
                                '<img src="http://datatables.net/media/images/logo-fade.png" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" />'
                            );

                        $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
                            .addClass( 'compact' )
                            .css( 'font-size', 'inherit' );
                    }
                }
            ]
    });

**External code:**

//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.print.min.js

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css
```

Comment: I'm glad to help

Answer (score 4):

Your "Edit 1" was on the right track but with one error.  I have corrected code below.  Doing it this way makes the title dynamic, i.e.; it is generated at print time.  This allows you to   Otherwise, the title is fixed at the string when the print button is created...

```
var table = $('table').DataTable({
    buttons: [
        extend: 'print',
        title: function(){
            var printTitle = 'New Title';
            return printTitle
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Datatables buttons](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) extension its not about what your trying to achieve, just use the caption tag

```
<table>
    <caption id="tablecaption"></caption>
    ....
</table>

$('#tablecaption').text(foo.title);
```